# How to take screen shots of all page links in a web site automatically in Firefox using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

- How to take screen shots of all page links in a web site automatically in Firefox using Selenium Web Driver?

  1. Tools, I am using:

     - selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar
     - Eclipse [JUNO] for Java Codding
  2. Done:

     - My code taking screen shots of Home Page after that it clicks on first Menu Item using its Element ID.
     - I have implemented the java code for all Links to be Load and then to take the Screen shots.
  3. Problem:

     - After Loading that First Linked Page, it is not taking screen shot of that page though java program is still in running state.
     - If any buddy can Solve this Problem then it will be very helpful for me.....

Answer (score 1):

Hope this code will works..

```
File screenshot = new File("D:\\screenshot1.png");
File tmpScreenshot = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
FileUtils.copyFile(tmpScreenshot, screenshot);
System.out.println("the screenshot printed at:- " + screenshot.getAbsolutePath());
```